# Как из ответа json выводить только баланс

Tags: php, json

Приходит ответ от сервера в формате json, надо вывести только баланс, как 
это сделать ?

Делаю `var_dump($smsaero_api->balance());`:

```
array(3) {
   ["success"]=> bool(true)
   ["data"]=> array(1) {
      ["balance"]=> $ float(3.46)
   }
   ["message"]=> NULL
}
```

Пытался вывести так:

```
$obj = json_decode($smsaero_api->balance());
print $obj->{'balance'};
```

Comment: может перебором массива  foreach. но я не знаю как, подскажите плиз

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка в том, что вы указываете не полный путь к  значению,  упускаете элемент `data`:

Полный вариант кода:

```
$obj = $smsaero_api->balance();
echo $obj['data']['balance'];
```

Comment: include_once('SmsaeroApiV2.class.php');
    use SmsaeroApiV2\SmsaeroApiV2;

    $smsaero_api = new SmsaeroApiV2('mail@mail', 'FeBa6vM', 'GO');
    var_dump($smsaero_api->balance()) // Запрос баланса
 
 $obj = json_decode($smsaero_api->balance())->data->balance;
print $obj->{'balance'};

Comment: @ИльяПим, я исправил ответ, посмотрите

Comment: @ИльяПим, вы же вывели сюда значение `$obj = json_decode($smsaero_api->balance())->data->balance`, зачем вы еще раз запрос к нему делаете через `print $obj->{'balance'};`, просто укажите `print $obj;`

Comment: ничего не выводит :( белый экран, а если  var_dump($smsaero_api->balance());  то выводит массив

Comment: @ИльяПим, еще раз ответ мой смотрите, полный код выложил

Comment: 'include_once('SmsaeroApiV2.class.php');
    use SmsaeroApiV2\SmsaeroApiV2;

    $smsaero_api = new SmsaeroApiV2('yandex.ru', 'FeBa6vM6', 'UDIO'); 

    var_dump($smsaero_api->balance()); 
 
 
$obj = json_decode($smsaero_api->balance());
echo $obj->{'data'}->{'balance'};'

Comment: @ИльяПим, ну и?

Comment: var_dump выводится и всё)

Comment: @ИльяПим, ахахах, а зачем мы делаем json_decode? Если там он не нужен?

Comment: @ИльяПим, сейчас исправлю

Comment: @ИльяПим, посмотрите ответ

Comment: еее, спасибо братан !

Comment: @ИльяПим, пожалуйста, что-то я тоже тупанул в начале)

Comment: а ты мне не поможешь ещё разок ?)))

Comment: а то я тупой :(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/863709/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-api-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%81-%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B0