# помогите разобраться с api смс шлюза

Tags: php, json

есть api сервиса

```
<?php

namespace SmsaeroApiV2;

    class SmsaeroApiV2
    {
        const URL_SMSAERO_API = 'https://gate.smsaero.ru/v2';
        private $email = 'yandex.ru'; //Ваш логин|email
        private $api_key = 'F6ebpkmkOYcIsA'; 
        private $sign = 'name'; //Подпись по умолчанию

        public function __construct($email, $api_key, $sign = false){
            $this->email = $email;
            $this->api_key = $api_key;
            if ($sign) {
                $this->sign = $sign;
            }
        }


        private function curl_post($url, array $post = NULL, array $options = array()){
            $defaults = array(
                CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => 1,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post),
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                CURLOPT_USERPWD => $this->email . ":" . $this->api_key,
                CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
            );

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults));
            if (!$result = curl_exec($ch)) {
                return curl_error($ch);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            return $result;
        }
        public function send($number, $text, $channel, $dateSend = null, $callbackUrl = null){
            return json_decode(self::curl_post(self::URL_SMSAERO_API . '/sms/send/', [
                is_array($number) ? 'numbers' : 'number' => $number,
                'sign' => $this->sign,
                'text' => $text,
                'channel' => $channel,
                'dateSend' => $dateSend,
                'callbackUrl' => $callbackUrl
            ]), true);
        }
}

?>
<?
    $number=$_POST['number'];
$text=$_POST['text'];


$smsaero_api->send(['$number'],'$text', 'DIGITAL');
```

и форма

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Введите телефон">
                </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" name="text" placeholder="текст">
                </div>


                <button type="submit" class="btn">Отправить форму</button>
            </form>
```

почему не работает ?

Comment: Где у вас запрос к классу `SmsaeroApiV2` и в форме где обработчик?

Comment: <form action="1.php" method="POST">
         <legend>Заголовок формы</legend>

         
        
         <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Введите телефон">
         </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" name="text" placeholder="текст">
         </div>
         
        
         <button type="submit" class="btn">Отправить форму</button>
        </form>

Comment: запрос к классу я делаю в 1.php $smsaero_api = new SmsaeroApiV2('yandex.ru', 'mkOYcIsA', 'SIGN');

Comment: как мне дальше функцию использовать send

Comment: $test = ($smsaero_api->send(['$number'],'$text', 'DIGITAL')); 
$number=$_POST['number'];
$text=$_POST['text'];

Comment: так тоже ничего не происходит :(

Comment: $smsaero_api->send(['number'],'text', 'DIGITAL'); 
и так тоже ничего

Comment: завтра утром/днем гляну

Comment: ну что, как это работает ?)

Comment: всё, разобрался

Answer (score 0):

```
$smsaero_api->send([$number],$text, 'DIGITAL');
```